# Как валидировать XPath?

Tags: c#, xml

В общем, валидирую таким образом `XPathExpression.Compile(xPath);`, но почему-то если на вход подать такой XPath `root/NumArea[Type = (1,2,3)]`, то падаю с ошибкой

> error: "/root/NumArea[Type = ('1','2','3')]" имеет недопустимый
> указатель (token)

Хотя Altova XMLSpy его спокойно обрабатывает. Вроде, в MSDN написано, что XPath 2.0 поддерживается.

Странно...

Comment: XML 2.0 - такой версии нет в природе. Имеется в виду XPath 2.0? Его поддержки нет в C# и .NET, насколько мне известно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да да... Да, уже понял. Пришлось какой-то левый нугет пакет поставить для этого.